# Angularjs ng-pattern missbehaviour with regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex, angularjs, validation

I have the following html with angularJs :

```
<input id="subjectCode"
                       name="subjectCode"
                       class="form-control input-md"
                       required
                       type="text"
                       ng-model="subjectCode"
                       ng-minlength="3"
                       ng-pattern="/^[A-Z0-9]+$/i">
```

The above code validate the text input versus minimum 3 characters that should be either A-Z capital letters or digits 0-9. This is validated to show error and set css to highlight mismatch as following:

```
<div class="form-group"
             ng-class="{ 'has-error':
                            myform.subjectCode.$invalid
                             && fahrasform.subjectCode.$dirty,
                        'has-success':
                            !myform.subjectCode.$invalid
                            && fahrasform.subjectCode.$dirty }">
```

The problem is that angularjs does not set $invalid to true if I use small letters while it sets it to false for other cases like entering international letters or special characters.

So, any suggestions?

Comment: I am using ng-minlength angularjs directive to limit number of charachters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace with this code:

```
<input id="subjectCode"
                       name="subjectCode"
                       class="form-control input-md"
                       required
                       type="text"
                       ng-model="subjectCode"
                       ng-minlength="3"
                       ng-pattern="/^[A-Z0-9]*$/">
```

`ng-pattern="/^[A-Z0-9]+$/i"` in this regular expression `/i` Perform case-insensitive matching.that's you have done mistake

Comment: Yes that was the source of problem